# when i use pyinstaller in python win32:PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied

Tags: python, pyinstaller, errno, permissionerror

i can make it an executable with pyinstaller in win64, and open the cmd using administrator privilege is not work.
[PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9QTK.png)

i use the pdfplumbert, re,copy, xlwt, os, sys in my file

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed mine because Windows Power Toys apparently stops me from creating the executable.